# Ошибка ValueError. Программа думает, что переменная не int, но в файле считываются только целые числа

Tags: python

```
with open("graf.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        data = line.split()
        n = data[0]
        e = data[1]
        e = int(e)
        n = int(n)

    v = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(e):
        r, c = map(int, input())
    v[r-1][c-1] = v[c-1][r-1] = 1
    for s in v:
        k = sum(s)
    print(k)
```

В файле, в 2 столбика, записаны только целые числа, без точек. Присвоил им специально значение int. Программа ругается только на переменную n
Почему так? Что можно исправить?

Файл:

```
637 961
244 735
703 496
340 234
```

Comment: Отладчик использовать пробовали?

Comment: У переменной е, добавляется пробел, это я выяснил
Как этот пробел можно удалить?)
Чтобы переменная была int?

Comment: И как применять .strip()?

Comment: Но это совсем не помогло

Comment: Но и это так же, ничего не изменило
e переменная почему-то смогла стать int
А переменная n почему-то не может

Comment: значит, не пробел добавляется и не перевод строки. может быть, табуляция

Comment: В файл не могут значения типа int записаться, не чеши.

Comment: "Ошибка ValueError. Программа думает, что переменная не int, но в файле считываются только целые числа" Что это за отсебятина, покажи  нормальный Traceback.

Comment: Почему бы просто не показать как надо тогда?
Тогда чесать перестану

Comment: line = file.readlines() values = line.split(' ') values - type tuple right_value, left_value = values